# Custom Datatables.net Column Visibility Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I need to style/customise Datatables.net Column Visibility dropdown. I'm using Datatables to show data from a table with dozens of columns and the current dropdown styling doesn't work well in this case.
I would like to know if its possible to customise the dropdown from the current styling to this:

[image: Current Dropdown Style]

[image: Preferred Styling]

I'm currently using Bootstrap to style the Datatables plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came out with a workaround. 
After the table is loaded i add a click event to the Column Visibility dropdown and group all the links into bootstrap columns:

```
/* Group all links in column visibility dropdown into columns */
dt.on('init', function (e)
{
    $("a.buttons-colvis").on("click", function ()
    {           
        var columnLinks = $(".dt-button-collection").find("a");

        for (var i = 0; i < columnLinks.length; i += 12)
        {
            columnLinks.slice(i, i + 12).wrapAll("<div class='col-md-3'></div>");
        }
    });
});
```

That solved my issue.